# Hibernate: permission checking on changing entity's fields

Tags: java, hibernate, aspectj

I've got something like that Hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_ent")
public class MyEntity {
  private field String one;
  private field String two;
  private field String three;
  // and so on...
}
```

I've got a few user roles, each of them have different rights on `MyEntity`. For example `admin` has rights to modify the `one` and `two` fields, `custom_user` has rights to modify `three` and `two` fields and so on.

***Problem:*** I should check in my request handler  if user modified only fields he has rights to modify. And I don't know the right way to do that.

I suppose two possible escapes:

1. Two write AspectJ annotations on each field, which enumerate the roles which have rights to modify the field. But it seems very ugly and complex (because I'll overhelm my code with AspectJ annotations).
2. To get the entity's modified fields list. It seems very attractive but how could I achieved that? For example, can I write some interceptor which put all modified entity's fileds names to the list.

***Question:*** *How can I write Hibernate entity permissions checking on changing entity fileds?*

Comment: How do you manage your rolls? Do you have a security framework such as Apache Shiro or spring Security? Running within an EJB container?

Comment: @orid no, any security framework, just some AspectJ annotations on handler-methods (means this request is allowed for admin and that for user). But it is suitable for request role separation, but not for field modification.

Comment: _To get the entity's modified fields list._ You can take a look [Interceptor.onFlushDirty](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onFlushDirty) but this happens late, before session flush, and you'll need some mechanism to plug your roles in

Comment: @orid it's too late. I use the hibernate conversation, it means that I use FlushMode.MANUAL. I invoke `session.flush()` only at the end of the conversation, so the first methods of the conversation doesn't call any `flush()`